# Can I replicate from SQL Server 2012 Express to SQL Server 2012 Express somehow?

Tags: sql, replication, sql-server-express

I am thinking this may not be possible as standard, but can I publish replication using SQL Server 2012 Express and subscribe with SQL Server 2012 Express? I am wanting to create a fail over between 2x VM's in an Zure Availability set.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

No.  SQL Server Express cannot serve as a Distributor or Publisher.  SQL Server Express can only serve as a Subscriber to Transactional, Snapshot, and Merge publications.  You will need an instance of at least Standard Edition or higher to create a publication.

[Replication Considerations (SQL Server Express)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165686.aspx)

> SQL Server Express cannot serve as a Publisher or Distributor.